# More efficient methods than nested for loops in R -- matching

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I'm trying to match people when they have identical names, last names, and first names, and keep the smallest numerical value for IDs.

I've created a test database below (much smaller than my actual dataset) and written a nested for-loop that looks like it's doing what it's supposed to.

*But it's slow as hell on bigger datasets.*

I'm relatively new to the apply functions, but they seem more intuitive for applying functions than data wrangling.

What's a more efficient alternative for what I'm doing here? I'm sure there's a simple solution that will have me shaking my head for asking here, but I'm not coming to it.

```
dta.test<- NULL
dta.test$Person_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11)
dta.test$FirstName <- c("John", "James", "John", "Alex", "Alexander", "Jonathan", "John", "Alex", "James", "John", "John")
dta.test$LastName <- c("Smith", "Jones", "Jones", "Jones", "Jones", "Smith", "Jones", "Smith", "Johnson", "Smith", "Smith")
dta.test$DOB <- c("2001-01-01", "2002-01-01", "2003-01-01", "2004-01-01", "2004-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2003-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2009-01-01")
dta.test$Actual_ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 8, 9, 1, 11)
dta.test <- as.data.frame(dta.test)

for(i in unique(dta.test$FirstName))
  for(j in unique(dta.test$LastName))
    for (k in unique (dta.test$DOB))
{
  {
    {
       dta.test$Person_id[dta.test$FirstName==i & dta.test$LastName==j & dta.test$DOB==k] <- min(dta.test$Person_id[dta.test$FirstName==i & dta.test$LastName==j & dta.test$DOB==k], na.rm=T)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
dta.test %>%
  group_by(FirstName, LastName, DOB) %>%
  mutate(Person_id = min(Person_id))

# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups: FirstName, LastName, DOB [9]
   # Person_id FirstName LastName DOB        Actual_ID
       # <dbl> <fct>     <fct>    <fct>          <dbl>
 # 1        1. John      Smith    2001-01-01        1.
 # 2        2. James     Jones    2002-01-01        2.
 # 3        3. John      Jones    2003-01-01        3.
 # 4        4. Alex      Jones    2004-01-01        4.
 # 5        5. Alexander Jones    2004-01-01        5.
 # 6        6. Jonathan  Smith    2001-01-01        6.
 # 7        3. John      Jones    2003-01-01        3.
 # 8        8. Alex      Smith    2006-01-01        8.
 # 9        9. James     Johnson  2006-01-01        9.
# 10        1. John      Smith    2001-01-01        1.
# 11       11. John      Smith    2009-01-01       11.
```

*EDIT* - Added Performance comparison

```
for_loop_approach <- function() {
    for(i in unique(dta.test$FirstName))
      for(j in unique(dta.test$LastName))
        for (k in unique (dta.test$DOB))
    {
      {
        {
           dta.test$Person_id[dta.test$FirstName==i & dta.test$LastName==j & dta.test$DOB==k] <- min(dta.test$Person_id[dta.test$FirstName==i & dta.test$LastName==j & dta.test$DOB==k], na.rm=T)
        }
      }
    }
}

dplyr_approach <- function() {
    require(dplyr)
    dta.test %>%
      group_by(FirstName, LastName, DOB) %>%
      mutate(Person_id = min(Person_id))
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(for_loop_approach(), dplyr_approach(), unit="relative", times=100L)

Unit: relative
                expr      min      lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 for_loop_approach() 20.97948 20.6478 18.8189 17.81437 17.91815 11.76743   100
    dplyr_approach()  1.00000  1.0000  1.0000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000   100
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Comment: I was juuuuust typing that out, +1

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Demonstrably more clear and concise. But what is the performance improvement and why?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a **base R approach** rather than dplyr and it comes out (according to microbenchmark) 7.46 times faster than the dplyr approach of CPak, and 139.4 times faster than the for loop approach. I've just used the `match` and `paste0` functions to get this working, and it will automatically retain the smallest matching id:

```
  dta.test[, "Actual_id"] <- match(paste0(dta.test$FirstName, dta.test$LastName, dta.test$DOB), paste0(dta.test$FirstName, dta.test$LastName, dta.test$DOB))
```

This approach also outputs it straight to a data frame, rather than a tibble (which you would need to extract the new column from, and add to your data frame):

```
   Person_id FirstName LastName        DOB Actual_id
1          1      John    Smith 2001-01-01         1
2          2     James    Jones 2002-01-01         2
3          3      John    Jones 2003-01-01         3
4          4      Alex    Jones 2004-01-01         4
5          5 Alexander    Jones 2004-01-01         5
6          6  Jonathan    Smith 2001-01-01         6
7          7      John    Jones 2003-01-01         3
8          8      Alex    Smith 2006-01-01         8
9          9     James  Johnson 2006-01-01         9
10        10      John    Smith 2001-01-01         1
11        11      John    Smith 2009-01-01        11
```

In your real data I expect the person id is not so simple (not just an integer) and doesn't run in numerical order, e.g.

```
dta.test$Person_id <- paste0(LETTERS[1:11],1:11)
```

You just need a small tweak to make this still work, to make it extract value from the `Person_id` column:

```
dta.test[, "Actual_id"] <- dta.test[match(paste0(dta.test$FirstName, dta.test$LastName, dta.test$DOB), paste0(dta.test$FirstName, dta.test$LastName, dta.test$DOB)), "Person_id"]
```

Giving:

```
   Person_id FirstName LastName        DOB Actual_id
1         A1      John    Smith 2001-01-01        A1
2         B2     James    Jones 2002-01-01        B2
3         C3      John    Jones 2003-01-01        C3
4         D4      Alex    Jones 2004-01-01        D4
5         E5 Alexander    Jones 2004-01-01        E5
6         F6  Jonathan    Smith 2001-01-01        F6
7         G7      John    Jones 2003-01-01        C3
8         H8      Alex    Smith 2006-01-01        H8
9         I9     James  Johnson 2006-01-01        I9
10       J10      John    Smith 2001-01-01        A1
11       K11      John    Smith 2009-01-01       K11
```

Comment: `match` will take the first match, not the minimum. Since OP specifically says that they want to keep the "smallest numerical value" you should sort first. (And to make a fair comparison, you should probably include the sort time in your benchmark since the other solutions don't require a sorted input.)

Comment: noted, adding in the sort, it still remains 4x faster

Answer (score 1):

A data table solution will probably be quickest on large data with lots of groups:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dta.test, key = c("FirstName", "LastName", "DOB"))
dta.test[, Actual_ID := min(Person_id, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(FirstName, LastName, DOB)]
```